# Use median for clustering, instead of average value

Tags: clustering, standard-deviation, median

I have a List of Files on which I run some statistical methods to get a rating between 0 and 1. 
Now i need to cluster the files for similarities. The easiest way i thought that would be is to use the average value of the rating and cluster by n*sigma. So the biggest part of all files will be in the range of `[avg-sigma, avg+sigma]`, then the next part will be `(avg+sigma, avg + 2*sigma]` and so on...

the problem is now if the values are very wide spreaded and have a distribution very close to one side of the range the clustering will be not very good.
 e.g. ten values of 0.01 and one value of 0.9 gives me avg of 0.1 but a median of 0.01... so a typical problem here...

now i think it would be better to use the median as a starting point but can i use the standard deviation to calculate my clusters? Or is there even a better method then using StdDev to create clusters?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The question is more whether your estimation of the distribution is good.

Since your data is in [0;1], I doubt that it will be remotely *normal* distributed.

If you want to continue with the normality assumption, try using the Median and MAD to estimate the distribution parameters.

But also consider other distributions, such as the beta distributions, which is naturally bounded to the domain [0;1]. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_distribution

Try to figure out what the appropriate distrbution is.